# How can i get my two icons side-by-side in my footer in React app?

Tags: css, reactjs, single-page-application, react-bootstrap, footer

I'm building a react portfolio. I'm struggling to style my footer. I only want to include icons of Github and LinkedIn on it. I want to have them side-by-side, and at the bottom of the screen once you reach the end of the page. Currently, the two icons are stacked vertically at the bottom, in the middle of the page, with a lot of space between the two rows.
I have react-bootstrap implemented.

Here's my footer component:

```
 import {AiFillGithub} from "react-icons/ai";
 import {AiFillLinkedin} from "react-icons/ai";

function Footer() {
    return (
        <footer className="justify-content-center font-link">
            <div className="primary flex-row center">
                <ul className="flex-row">
                    <li className="links">
            <a href="https://github.com/PhuongHoang68"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noreferrer"
            >
                <h3 className="icon"><AiFillGithub size="3rem"/></h3>
            </a>
            </li>
            <li className="links">
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/phuong-hoang-a0b4901a5/"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noreferrer"
            >
                <h3 className="icon"><AiFillLinkedin size="3rem"/></h3>
            </a>
            </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </footer>
    )
}

export default Footer;
```

Here's my related css:

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

footer {
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: auto;
  padding: 8px;
}
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: var(--dark);
  color: var(--light);
  font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;

}
```

Here's my app.js (only the parts related to the footer):

```
import Footer from './components/Footer';

        <div className="app">
            <Footer />
        </div>

    


export default App;
```

I have tried many methods and nothing is working. i have included the above code that is above. Please help me, I really appreciate it

Comment: Technically you should follow the style guidelines on allowed use and spacing from the vendors for these type of icons that are copyrighted or trademarked by them.  For example LinkedIn has a "width of the "I" times two" ref: https://brand.linkedin.com/downloads

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `ul` has class `flex-row` but does not have its `display` set as [`flex`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/flex/#enable-flex-behaviors), therefore the flex behavior is not enabled.

For a Bootstrap solution to fix this, perhaps try add `d-flex`, `justify-content-center`, `align-items-center` and (if the default list style also needed to be removed) [`list-unstyled`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/content/typography/#unstyled) to the `className` of `ul`.

Simplified demo on: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cqixbk?file=src/App.js)

```
<ul className="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center list-unstyled">
...
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I ended up applying flexbox and new css as : ```  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;``` and it worked